# I am not able to handle the Exception using JAX-RS

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, rest, jax-rs

This the NullPointerExceptionMapper class

```java
package com.sample.Exceptionhandler;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import response.Message;

@Provider
public class NullPointerExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<NullPointerException> {

    public Response toResponse(NullPointerException ex) {

        Message message=new Message(500,ex.getMessage(),200);
        return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).entity(message)
                .build();
    }
}
```

This is the Message class

```java
package response;

public class Message {

    private int status;
    private String message;
    private int code;

    public Message() {
    }

    public Message(int status, String message, int code) {
        super();
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

This is the Controller method

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/getOrder", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public List<PurchaseOrderHeaderDto> getOrders(){
    String exceptionOccured="NULL_POINTER";
    if(exceptionOccured.equalsIgnoreCase("NULL_POINTER")){
        throw new NullPointerException("Null Pointer Exception");
    }
    return purchaseImpl.GetPurchaseOrder();
}
```

I am not able to handle the Exception  thrown and  I am using JAX-RS for handling it, but it is not working  properly any suggestions are welcomed that would help me sort this out.

Comment: did you registered your provider ?

Comment: ya i have provided @Provider annotation

Comment: which JAX-RS Implementation are you using?

Comment: I am new to this soo i dont no much about this

Comment: Your code looks good. Ideally we should not handle NullPointerException,  NullPointerException means thr is some bug.You may try a clean build and redeploy.If nothing works you may try with Generic Exception class instead  of NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing JAX-RS with Spring MVC. Your controller code is Spring MVC and your attempt at exception handling with the `ExceptionMapper` is JAX-RS. These are two completely different and incompatible frameworks. For Spring MVC, you want to use a [`@ControllerAdvice`](https://medium.com/@jovannypcg/understanding-springs-controlleradvice-cd96a364033f) class.